# How do I perform an ARIMA test with the dataset souvenirtimeseries?

Tags: r, statistics, arima, forecast

I am a novice in R.
I am trying to perform an ARIMA test to perform a 10 year prediction on the above mentioned data set.

```
          Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
1987   1664.81   2397.53   2840.71   3547.29   3752.96   3714.74   4349.61   3566.34   5021.82   6423.48   7600.60  19756.21
1988   2499.81   5198.24   7225.14   4806.03   5900.88   4951.34   6179.12   4752.15   5496.43   5835.10  12600.08  28541.72
1989   4717.02   5702.63   9957.58   5304.78   6492.43   6630.80   7349.62   8176.62   8573.17   9690.50  15151.84  34061.01
1990   5921.10   5814.58  12421.25   6369.77   7609.12   7224.75   8121.22   7979.25   8093.06   8476.70  17914.66  30114.41
1991   4826.64   6470.23   9638.77   8821.17   8722.37  10209.48  11276.55  12552.22  11637.39  13606.89  21822.11  45060.69
1992   7615.03   9849.69  14558.40  11587.33   9332.56  13082.09  16732.78  19888.61  23933.38  25391.35  36024.80  80721.71
1993  10243.24  11266.88  21826.84  17357.33  15997.79  18601.53  26155.15  28586.52  30505.41  30821.33  46634.38 104660.67
```

However, when I type:

```
auto.arima(souvenirtimeseries)
Series: souvenirtimeseries 
ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,1)[12] 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1    sma1
      0.2401  -0.9013  0.7499
s.e.  0.1427   0.0709  0.1790

sigma^2 estimated as 16146440:  log likelihood=-693.69
AIC=1395.38   AICc=1395.98   BIC=1404.43
> fit <- arima(log((souvenirtimeseries)), c(1,1,1), seasonal=list(order= c(1,1,1), period=12))
> par(mfrow=c(1,1))
> pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 10*12)
> ts.plot(soi, 2,718^pred$pred, log="y", lty=c(1,3))
```

The result is not correct as I get something like this:

[image]

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
  ts.plot(soi, 2,718^pred$pred, log="y", lty=c(1,3))
```

has to be changed in:

```
ts.plot(soi, 2.718^pred$pred, log="y", lty=c(1,3))
```